# HTML relative content is rendered over fixed content

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a navbar, that is fixed at the top of the screen. This nav bar is `position: fixed;`, but it renders underneath my content, which is `position: relative;`. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the *value* of the `z-index` *property* of the `#navbar` to something high enough, e.g.:

```
#navbar {
  z-index: 999999; /* needs to be higher than the content's z-index (if defined) */
}
```

Just to make sure that it stays on *top* or in *front* of everything else.